# Finding VSCode extension extension id

Tags: visual-studio-code, vscode-extensions

I am currently writing a vscode extension where I require to bundle some files with the extension and on some command, I need to deploy those files at some destination directory (like building a scaffold). For this purpose, I was looking into using these two functions:

```js
const extensionPath = vscode.extensions.getExtension('extension.id').extensionUri.path;
const destinationPath = vscode.workspace.workspaceFolders[0].uri.path;
```

However, I had trouble finding the `extension.id`. If I use `vscode.extensions.all` to enumerate all the extensions, I see `undefined_publisher.<name>`. I believe this is because I have not published my extension yet, but in that case I guess the `undefined_publisher` part might change.

Is there any way I can locate my extension without using the publisher name?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The `ExtensionContext` object has path and uri properties.

It is the `context` from your `activate(context)` function.

See https://code.visualstudio.com/api/references/vscode-api#ExtensionContext

Comment: Thanks a ton guys. Exactly what I was looking for!